# Adaptive and general matplotlib/pyplot script / bash-like handling of variable names in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am a beginner in plotting things with pyplot.
I would like to create a general plotting script that can deal with a different number of files to plot (along a known and consistent naming scheme). The program, that I created so far, reads in the files and stores the data, that is to plot, as a 2D-array in another array called **datnames**. A except from the code is shown below:

```
# Add figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[25,40])

# Create first axis-object and plot first graph
ax = fig.add_subplot(4,1,1)
ax.plot(datnames[0][:,0] , datnames[0][:,1])

# Create second axis-object and plot second graph
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,1,2)
ax1.plot(datnames[1][:,0],datnames[1][:,1])
```

In this case I just had to plot two graphs.
The question now being: How can I generalize this, so that pyplot adapts the number of axis to the number of files that are to plot?
I was maybe thinking about some bash-like handling of the axis-names? Something along these lines:

```
for i in np.arange(NumberOfFiles):
   ax${i} = fig.add_subplot(NumberOfFiles,1,i)
   ax${i}.plot(xValues,yValues)
```

which is obviously a weird synthesis of bash and python...
Is there any way to implement such a handling of the variables in python3? (I have already read about storing the variables and values as elements of dictionaries, but I don't think that this is beneficial in this case).
Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Comment: What about `fig, axs = plt.subplots(NumberOfFiles, 1)` and then just for loop over axis? Btw, check PEP naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case for using a list:

```
ax = [] # initialize empty list
for i in np.arange(NumberOfFiles):
    ax[i] = fig.add_subplot(NumberOfFiles,1,i)
    ax[i].plot(xValues,yValues)
```

If you want to use something other than consecutive ordinals (i.e. integer numbers starting from 0), use a dictionary instead and initialize it with `ax={}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I had the misconception that the names for ax and ax1 were set for pyplot and not arbitrary.